# Create drop down on clickable table row

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I want to create a drop down after user clicks on a table row.How can i do this using bootstrap and JavaScript?

Here is My table

[image: Here is My table]

Comment: Please provide a code. What do you try to this time?

Comment: You can use the class xhide to hide and show rows

Comment: i don't want to hide rows,i just want to show drop down after mouse click on row

Answer (score -1):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".clickable-row").click(function(e) {
        if(e.target.id != "listItems"){
          $(this).find("#listItems").toggle();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

</div>
<table>
    <tr class='clickable-row' data-href='url://'>
        <td>1</td> 
        <td>ABC</td> 
        <td>123456789</td>
        <td>
          <select id="listItems">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
          </select>        
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='clickable-row' data-href='url://'>
        <td>2</td> 
        <td>BCD</td> 
        <td>123456789</td>
        <td>
          <select id="listItems">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
          </select>        
        </td>
    </tr>    
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks,but i want this drop down on the table row.and drop down will expand after mouse click

Comment: @Pranta is this what you are looking for?